# Use entity framework code first in SharePoint Solution

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, development, mvc

I am trying to create an entity framework code first in a SharePoint Solution.

Is it possible to use an entity framework code first in a SharePoint Solution?

If yes, then how?

Answer (score 2):

You don't mention what version of SharePoint you are using, but if you are using SharePoint 2013 or Online then you should look at the [Provider Hosted App Model](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/fp142381.aspx). This allows you to integrate a (mostly) standard MVC app with code first EF with SharePoint. The MVC app is actually hosted outside of SharePoint, and uses the [client object model](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/fp179912.aspx) to communicate with it.